# how to put ... if string length is over 12

Tags: javascript

```
facebook_user_name=facebook_info[0].url[j];
if(facebook_user_name.length>12)
{

}
```

how to put ... if string length is over 12.
For example, the name is aaaaaaaa bbbbbbb the result should be aaaaaaaa bbb...
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The "..." is a single character called an *ellipsis*, the HTML entitiy code is `&hellip;`. Looks ok with proportional fonts, but not so good with monospaced fonts.

Comment: Though truncating strings and appending an ellipsis when using proportional fonts can look kind of silly because (obviously) the total width of the field will vary depending on the data. Compare "iiiiii..." with "wwwwww...". (And `iiiiii...` and `wwwwww...`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var substring = facebook_user_name.substr(0, 12) + '...';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
facebook_user_name=facebook_info[0].url[j];
if(facebook_user_name.length > 12)
{
    facebook_user_name += "...";
}
```

Comment: That's not doing what he wants, though, that's just tacking on "..." to his string, not shortening it to 12 characters first.

Comment: he stated `the result should be..` and listed a 12 character long string followed by `...`. So I assume that is what he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: use the [substr()](http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) function, like this:

```
facebook_user_name=facebook_info[0].url[j];

if(facebook_user_name.length>12){
    facebook_user_name = facebook_user_name.substr(0, 12) + "...");
}
```

*Please note: the above code is untested and may contain errors.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the extra characters with an ellipsis (which is only one character), then:

```
facebook_user_name = facebook_user_name.substring(0, 12) + '\u2026';
```

so the total string length is 13. If you add 3 dots, the string will be 15 characters so you may as well display usernames up to 15 characters in full. If you want to display a maximum of 12 characters, then:

```
if (facebook_user_name.length > 12) {
    facebook_user_name = facebook_user_name.substring(0, 11) + '\u2026';
}
```

so now facebook_user_name is 12 characters long—11 characters of the name and one for the ellipsis.